Why is my Postgres migration using Alembic failing?
I'm having a tough time figuring out why my Alembic migration is failing with Postgres 17.
Here is the snippet from my Alembic upgrade function that fails:
op.execute("""
UPDATE reviews
SET
  config = json_build_object(
    'model', replace(model, '"', '\"'),
    'endpoint', json_build_object(
        'url', replace(uri, '"', '\"')
    )
  ),
  custom_data = COALESCE((
    SELECT json_object_agg(combined.key, combined.value)
    FROM (
      SELECT key, value FROM json_each_text(COALESCE(metadata, '{}'::json))
      UNION ALL
      SELECT key, value FROM json_each_text(COALESCE(rating, '{}'::json))
    ) AS combined
  ), '{}'::json);

""")

config and custom_metadata are newly-added columns I'm populating based on values in existing columns. They're both of type JSON.
Error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pg8000.dbapi.ProgrammingError) cannot deconstruct a scalar

metadata and rating are both nullable JSON columns. In the existing data I'm migrating, the values for metadata and rating are null for all rows. So, I'm at a loss in regards to what this error is referring to. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm going to say it is an issue with values in metadata and/or rating. I would look at the Postgres log, it should provide more information on what value failed.

Crank up the logging to show us the SQL update statement that alembic generated, plus the DDL to create the reviews table. As stated the OP is not yet a reprex. The problem seems to mostly be a "this UPDATE is broken" issue, and only peripherally about alembic sending such an insert command.
